# Android 4.4 + Parse.com query array of pointers

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

It's so wired parse query in array of pointer can't work on 4.4 below and everything working fine for 5 + ,

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> firstQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(CLASSNAME);
    firstQuery.whereEqualTo(COLOUMNNAME1, ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> secondQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(CLASSNAME);
    secondQuery.whereEqualTo(COLOUMNNAME2, ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    queries.add(firstQuery);
    queries.add(secondQuery);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
```

Second query is array of parse user pointers.

Note : In Android 5 return all matched data in both.
in Android 4.4 return all matched data in first query only.

Comment: What's the first query doing differently exactly?

Comment: Did you use parse debug logging to make sure it's going to the same database?

Comment: @JakeT. first query filter in coloumn of parse user and working for both 4.4 and 5 +

Comment: @nasch yes same db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's been a fix for this as of 5 days ago, though there isn't additional feedback that it has worked: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/175

Make sure you're on the latest parse-server and maybe it'll work.

Beyond that, two solutions are offered: 
1) Refactor your code to store arrays of objectIds rather than pointers. This is not broken.

2) Refactor your code to instead of calling `whereEqualTo`, you call `whereContainsAll`, and pass a single element array with the pointer you need. This function does not seem broken.

Comment: Thank you it's working now after using whereContainsAll